# Replace text and variations

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I have a string that follows a number in a txt file, and want to replace that string with the following number. So could i replace, for instance, the string "text 1" and any of its variations such as "text 2", "text 6", text 10", "text 1553", etc.?

Im using sed:

```
sed 's/text 1/new text/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output as your requirements so far are very vague and ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use capturing group.

```
sed 's/text \([[:digit:]]\+\)/\1/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'text 34 text 58' | sed 's/\btext \([[:digit:]]\+\)/\1/g'
34 58
```